# Adding Footer navigation in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, navigation

I need to have footer navigation menu similar to the one i have used for top navigation in SharePoint 2010. But the catch is it should be created with diffrent UI i.e CSS classes may get changed.

Also i have tried copying the SharePoint:aspmenu for top navigation and pasted for footer too but i could not mofify the font size color etc as top navigation and footer using same CSS that ways.

Let me know how should i go forward!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the ASPMenu control inside of another container and then override the CSS inheritance for that container so that it doesn't pick up the normal CSS.